# Упал Apache сам по себе

Tags: apache, apache2

Всем привет , все работало нормально , но вдруг в один прекрасный день (тк сегодня) включаю комп и вижу там такое.

Failed to start LSB: Apache2

бывало ли такое еще у кого ?
Есть идеи как исправить.

Comment: `error_log` покажите.

Comment: да , кажется нашел проблему , вот AH00526: Syntax error on line 192 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: